# create UIView with xib in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I want to create a Custom View with xib,
So I did CreateTask.xib that contain a TextField
and class is CustomUIView: UIView

I follow this step from 
http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/creating-custom-user-interface-files-with-xib-in-xcode-6-and-swift/

```
 
import UIKit
```

class CreateTaskView: UIView {

`@IBOutlet weak var taskNameField: UITextField!
var nibView: UIView!

var taskName: String? {
    get {
        if taskNameField == nil {
            return "taskNameField is nil"
        }
        if let s = taskNameField.text {
            return s
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    print("infinite loop")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}



func setup() {
    nibView = loadViewFromNib()
    nibView.frame = bounds
    nibView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth ,UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(nibView)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CreateTask", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
}`

}

when i instance CreateTaskView, that CreateTaskView was created infinite by loadViewFromNib(), I think it probably the reason is "xib class is CustomUIView", so I take it out.

but i can't get the UITextField outlet in xib now, how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to create nib from the class itself, instead the class that creates the instance of the customview should load the view with its nib file. An Objective-C example:

```
CustomView *myView = (CustomView *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewXIB" owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
```

It will create the instance of `CustomView` class by using its corresponding XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `CreateTask.xib` and tap on File's Owner tab
2. set the owner of the xib by tapping `Identity Inspector`and set the custom class as `CreateTaskView`
3. then try creating the outlet of textfield to `CreateTaskView`